# How to switch off the Mesh on an ellipsoidal RegionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to draw 3D ellipsoids, the simplest of which is

```
RegionPlot3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[3]], Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

How can I switch off the black mesh? `Mesh -> None` doesn't do anything here.

## update

WR support recommends to use

```
RegionPlot3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[3]], BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

which works fine.

Comment: I’m perplexed, but that’s not unusual, haha! It looks, to me, though, like some of the upper right portion has no meshing that appears.

Comment: Yes @CATrevillian the mesh is buggy and doesn't cover a triangle on the sphere.

Comment: maybe post-processing to remove `Line`s: `RegionPlot3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[3]]]/. Line->({}&)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegionPlot[]`/`RegionPlot3D[]` predate regions, and my impression is that they are not as robust on regions as on predicates.  `DiscretizeRegion` offers more control.  That said, I don't understand why some edges of the polygons do not appear.  I'd say it was a bug.  (Either all should appear or none.)

Also the `Mesh` option in plotting is different from the `Mesh` in `MeshRegion`.  It's related to mesh functions in plotting, but in regions, it's related to triangulation.

```
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[3]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I thought that this is what `RegionPlot3D` does internally anyway. So is this a way to circumvent a bug?

Comment: Ah! How curious. Was the OP not discretized enough? Or simply just a matter of how it is internally implemented, and perhaps changing styles for the OP would also not carry properly?

Comment: @Roman  It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: OK I've sent WR a message about this.